# single CXF endpoint to accept SOAP message for different namespace versions

Tags: web-services, soap, cxf, apache-camel

As of now, we have three different webservice endpoint for each type of Schema Version i.e  has different namespaces.

We are using camel-cxf 2.8.0.

e.g

1. Schema with Namespace: `http: //www.example.org/archive/schema/REL-5-1-2 has cxf endpoint cxf://http: //hostname.com:1111/soap/greet`
2. Schema with Namespace: `http: //www.example.org/archive/schema/REL-6-1-0 cxf://http: //hostname.com:2222/soap/greet`
3. Schema with Namespace `http: //www.example.org/archive/schema/REL-6-1-4 cxf://http: //hostname.com:3333/soap/greet`

each cxf endpoint is configured in this way:

`cxf://http: //hostname.com:<port>/soap/greet?serviceClass=org.example.schemas.rel610.GreetServicePortType&bus=#cxf;`

Now,  We have to expose only single webservice endpoint that can accept request for all these schemas and should do internal routing based on the namespace.
I tied to find articles that may have suggested similar implementations but could see anything like this.

Can anyone suggest me if there is way I can expose a single endpoint for this scenario?
Any suggestion would be helpful.

Thanks,
ashwin74268

Comment: Do you have examples of these schemas? I would not try and determine the namespace I would use SOA principles as Service Facade and Service Encapsulation to achieve this. Exposing the namespaces in the newly created service means your consumers will be tightly bound to these namespaces thus changing i.e. adding or removing a name space will create problems.

Comment: Here is the link to one of the wsdl sample.
http://txs.io/m1xb

Similarly, there are two more wsdls.  We are using RouteBuilder to expose camel route for these soap webservices

Comment: I had a look at the WSDL's and XSD.'s. Just a question or two to help me formulate an answer. You essentially want to take all these various versions of the WSDL's and expose one service WSDL that can cater for all the various versions? Also  will this new one service be exposed to external users or will it only be used by internal users?

Comment: I would like to expose only one service  which can accept the SOAP request on it and then based on the version in namespace it can route internally to different CXF endpoints and finally respond back with the response with version of original request. This webservice will be exposed to external users as well.

Comment: @Ashwin - you found a solution?